# OkHttp and Retrofit infinite Post request in background

Tags: android, post, retrofit2, okhttp

On random devices POST request gets stuck and do infinite loops which can be seen on back-end logs.

From logs it can be seen that users continues using app without knowing that it is looping network requests.

Some users even contacted us because our app uses a lot of mobile data in background.

I found this [problem](https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace) for `OkHttp`, but it should be gone when setting `.retryOnConnectionFailure()` to false, but it does not work.

Also there is a problem with updating library to newest version because our app min sdk is 16, and since 
version `3.12.1`, library supports only 21+. Newest version is `4.6.0`

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 3.12.11 which works on API 16 and has a fix for this.
https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-31211

Comment: Done that this morning, thank you, will wait for results. If it will work I will accept the answer.

Comment: Had one looping user straight after update with newest OkHttp `3.12.11` version.... This issue is annoying and can not replicate it, back-end guys going crazy about it

Comment: Thinking already to do post request without using this library

Comment: Yeah, what a hassle! There might be another fix in the 4.6.x branch to backport.